# jquery arrays comparison with substrings and case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

Folks
I have a jquery function requirement that will compare two arrays.

listA = [' APPLE', 'banana', 'orange']
listB = [ 'BANANA ','appl']

ok so in above example, I need function to return "true".
Basically what I need is a way to

- Strip each word in both arrays to get rid of leading and trailing spaces.
- Perform comparison which needs to be case insensitive.
- Compare substring level, which means 'appl' does exist within ' APPLE', so it should be true

my code so far

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
Array.prototype.contains = function(array) {
return array.every(function(item) {

    array = $.map(this, function(value){
       return value.replace(/ /g, '').toUpperCase();
    });

    return array.indexOf(item.replace(/ /g, '').toUpperCase()) >= 0;
}, this);
}

var result = [' APPLE', 'banana ', 'orange'].contains([ ' BANANA',' Appl ']);
alert(result);

});
```

so in above code example, it should return "true"

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the **Array.prototype.contains** function as below, this will remove the leading and trailing spaces and use a case insensitive comparison under the **map** function:

```js
Array.prototype.contains = function(array) {
    return array.every(function(item) {
        var searchResult = this.map(function(i) {
            return i.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(item.trim().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        });

        return searchResult.includes(true);
    }, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return` within `array.every( .. )`

use a counter.
Then ..

`return counter == array.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() methods when doing the comparison.

for example:

```
let areEqual = str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase();
```